# How can I hide settings' results from windows search box

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, system-modification

I wondered if it was possible to disable settings and control panel's results in the windows search box as follow :

[image: These settings are annoying]

Also, I would love to know if the "Settings" tab seen above can also be disabled ? (and even all others while we're at it)

I tried to find it in Windows system files but couldn't find anything.
Thanks for your time and answers !

Edit : I am fine with disabling the Windows Search box as a whole if I can still type "msconfig" and have a result, like this : (this is a previous version of windows but I think it might be doable to disable the extended right and the top tabs) :

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to invent some kind of family protection?

Comment: @John I didn't ask for that, I tried to get rid of the Settings' App and control panel's results.

Comment: @harrymc I guess so but I found a workaround.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way I found as a lazy person is to rename SearchApp.exe to SearchApp.exe.bak (or anything else, but no .exe) (In the C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy)

I know it is dangerous for the computer, but it seems to be working for now.

Comment: Windows has got many tools for limiting users - no need to mutilate it for doing that.

Comment: @harrymc then how, without the Group Policy, can I disable the entirety of the search box ? Even with it, if we're at that point where there is no option anywhere else to do so.

Comment: You don't need to disable the search, just to disable the user's ability to use these utilities.

Comment: then how, because opening the start menu and typing on your keyboard allows the user to search already.

Comment: Seeing is not the same as executing. Give the others a standard user account, then they cannot use any utility that requires administrator permissions. Other finer methods also exist with [Help protect your family online with Windows Security](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help-protect-your-family-online-with-windows-security-5e8b9fd8-8372-dba0-eba2-46da8e407026).

Comment: @harrymc I need to clarify even more : it's on my own session that I want to disable it.

Which means there is no other method, apart from removing myself from the admin group and so on, which is quite the hassle.

Thanks for your time though